# Get Group membership of group in Azure AD with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have two groups and one user.

Group A contains Group B.
Group B contains User X.

Now I want to get group A by ObjectId of user X.
In Azure GUI there is a preview for "Group membership" in groups so you can see "parent groups" but how to do this in Powershell?

Or is there a way to get "Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where Members contains User x" ?

Group A and B have a specific wording. Group A begins with "role-" and group B begins with "ad-". For sure there a hundred other groups beginning with same prefix.

Best,
Wyphorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script below.

In my sample,
group `role-test` contains group `ad-test`, `ad-test` contains user `X`. And group `role-test2` contains group `ad-test1`, `ad-test1` also contains user `X`. So the result should be `role-test` and `role-test2`.

```
$adgs = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId "<object-id of user X>" | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'ad-*'}
$rolegs = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'role-*'}
foreach($adg in $adgs){
    foreach($roleg in $rolegs){
    $member = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $roleg.ObjectId | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $adg.DisplayName}
    if($member){
        Write-Host DisplayName: $roleg.DisplayName ObjectId: $roleg.ObjectId
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I wrote some function for this. I hoped for some functionality not to  traverse through all groups. But its okay for me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, If we want to use User X to get Group A, we must ensure that no groups contain Group A and Group A is the only group that contains User X indirectly. Otherwise, we just can get a list of the groups that contain User X indirectly

```
#get the ObjectId of the groups whose members contain the user
$Groups = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.GroupIdsForMembershipCheck
$r=(Get-AzureADGroup -all $true).ObjectId
$r[$r.Count]
$id=@() 
for($i=0 ; $i -lt ([math]::Ceiling($r.Count/20)) ; $i++ ){


   $strat =0+ 20*$i
   $end =20*($i+1) -1


    if($end -ge $r.Count){
      $end = $r.count -1
    }
    $Groups.GroupIds= $r[$strat..$end]
    $result=Select-AzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf -ObjectId <user object id> -GroupIdsForMembershipCheck $Groups 

    if( $result -ne $null){
      $id += $result

    }
}


#get the groups' ObjectId that  the user is a direct member of
$id1 =(Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId <user object id> | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "Group"}).ObjectId

# get the groups' ObjectId that  the user is not a direct member of
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$caps=$id
for($i=0; $i -lt $id1.Count ; $i++){

  $caps.Remove($id1[$i])

}

#get the group
Foreach($id in $caps){
   Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $id

}
```